# How to print a non-static google map (v3 api)

Tags: firefox, google-maps, printing

I would like to ask if there is any way to print a google map which is showing a direction overlay?

- I hv tried
  http://abcoder.com/google/google-map-api/print-button-for-google-map-api/ with google map javascript api v3,
  but the map cannot be shown.
- I hv also tried to use static google
  map, however Static Maps API URLs can
  be a maximum of approximately 2,000
  characters only, as a result my map
  cannot be shown again

can anyone tell me if there is any way to solve the problem?? thx

Comment: Now I am using 
window.opener.document.getElementById("map_content").cloneNode(true);
to get the map and the route from the parent html. Using this way, I am able to print the img using chrome, but when i use firefox 3.6.10 to print the img, only the route can be printed out but map is not able to be printed, is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.
Now I am able to print the dynamic map on firefox successfully.
Here is some idea of how I achieved this:

after google maps drew the route, i tried to inspect the html using firebug
and i found that the problem about **firefox cant print google map successfully** is somehow because of the "style" of the div of the map.

img1 : http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/KNWAznhah3Fv0CxdJ7_anUNXPgy_jUWAJdQ2OJnhc_g?feat=directlink

By deleting the corresponding div (refer to img1) using javascript, the map and the route can be printed correctly in firefox.

I am not sure if this is violating the rules in using Google map api, it's better for you to  check carefully before using this method.

--Mark

Comment: And u may find that if the map contain "marker", the **firefox will print out a white box instead of the marker**, this can also be solved

img2 :  http://www.geocities.jp/chiwa1015jp/marker.png

First of all, (refer to img2) remove two divs (z-index:102 and z-index:103), one of them is holding the shadow of the marker.
In the div (with z-index:105), it is holding the marker img, remove the "opacity: 0.01" this style from the corresponding div can solve the blank markers problem.


Hope the above methods can also solve ur problems~ 
=)

Comment: Your links with images are dead now.

Comment: Sorry, this is a new image link, see if it works
http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/KNWAznhah3Fv0CxdJ7_anUNXPgy_jUWAJdQ2OJnhc_g?feat=directlink